# PHP - create DateTime from variable

Tags: php, datetime

I have variable like this:

```
$dateStr = "first day of January ' . (new DateTime())->format('Y') . ' 23:59:59";
```

now I want to create a `\DateTime` from this... So I'm trying like this:

```
$date = new \DateTime('\'' . $dateStr .'\'');
```

But it gaves error...

```
Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ('first day of January ' . (new DateTime())->format('Y') . ' 23:59:59') at position 0 ('): Unexpected character
```

my code:
$dateStr = "first day of January ' . (new DateTime())->format('Y') . ' 23:59:59";

/* works when used like this */

```
$dateStr = "first day of January ' . (new DateTime())->format('Y') . ' 23:59:59";

$date2 = new DateTime('first day of January ' . (new DateTime())->format('Y') . ' 23:59:59');
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

/* fails when used like this */
$date = new DateTime('\'' . $dateStr . '\'');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Working fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/829da64825758f35e26087b2f9a81d93421b9941

Comment: you have problem with quotes, see my answer below

Comment: You should consider using `DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )` and convert the format to the accepted formats of `DateTime` to have a future compatible solution.

Comment: The DateTime constructor is very permissive with its arguments but not as much as to accept arbitrary PHP code!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If that's exactly the string you have to use, it should be evaluated as PHP code.

```
$date = new DateTime(eval('return \'' . $dateStr . '\';'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

However using `eval()` and having your code presented in string variables or database is strongly discouraged and considered a harmful practice.

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
$dateStr = "first day of January " . (new DateTime())->format('Y') . " 23:59:59";
/* works when used like this */
$date2 = new DateTime('first day of January ' . (new DateTime())->format('Y') . ' 23:59:59');
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
/* fails when used like this */
$date = new \DateTime($dateStr);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```